# Is there a way to skip specific days in Carbon?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have a calculate shipping days method. I need to be able to add days onto a Carbon instance but i need to skip adding a day based on if its a specific day of the week, not necessarily Saturday/Sunday, it could be Monday or Tuesday as well. I cant seem to find anything in the Carbon Docs that specifies blacklisting certain days of the week when adding days.

Comment: Is that last question really needed? I mean, who else should do it?

Comment: @Andreas you are right. kinda dumb. removed it

Comment: A question that has nothing more than a description of the problem generally gets no attention, at least not the correct attention. Add more specific what the issue is. "I ship on this date, 10 days of shipping, not Mondays, expected result <some date>, this code did not work, what did I do wrong." That is missing...

Comment: Trying to translate assorted holidays into code is an incredibly non-trivial problem to solve. This is why nearly everyone simply tells you "5-7 business days", because it's so simple for a human to figure out that it's almost implicit.

Answer (score 0):

A library for Carbon helps to set open/closed days in a week and so you can:

https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time

And you could do:

```
BusinessTime::enable(Carbon::class, [
  'monday'.   => [],
  'tuesday'   => ['00:00-24:00'],
  'wednesday' => ['00:00-24:00'],
  'thursday'  => ['00:00-24:00'],
  'friday'    => [],
  'saturday'  => ['00:00-24:00'],
  'sunday'    => ['00:00-24:00'],
]);

$date = Carbon::parse('2019-06-01');

echo $date->addOpenTime('4 days');
```

This add 4 days skipping Friday and Monday.

You could basically get the same result with a loop adding days one by one, but it will be as slow as the interval is big. To optimize the operation, you should first add complete weeks:

```
$daysToAdd = 36;
$skippedDays = ['Monday', 'Friday'];
$daysPerWeek = 7 - count($skippedDays);
$completeWeeks = floor($daysToAdd / $daysPerWeek);

function skip(CarbonInterface $date, array $skippedDays): CarbonInterface {
  $date = $date->copy(); // if not using CarbonImmutable

  while (in_array($date->format('l'), $skippedDays)) {
    $date = $date->addDay();
  }

  return $date;
}

$start = Carbon::now(); // Or whatever date
$end = $start->copy()->addWeeks($completeWeeks); // ->copy() not needed if you use CarbonImmutable
$end = skip($end, $skippedDays);

// For each remaining days
for ($i = $daysToAdd % $daysPerWeek; $i--; $i > 0) {
  $end = skip($end->addDay(), $skippedDays);
}
```

This is a vanilla version for your specific case, but if you think someday, you will have to deal with hour-intervals/hour-precision instead of days, or will have special days (like holidays exceptions), then you should definitely use `cmixin/business-time` (link above).